# Entities Framework SaveChanges() Not Working

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6, asp.net-web-api2

I have a problem when calling API for update and `savechanges()` is not working (the data is not update).

However, when I add `Thread.Sleep(1000);` the data update correctly.

**Working Methods**

```
public async Task<ResponseBaseModel> AddOrderRemark2(AddOrderRemarkRequestModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (ChatEntities context = new ChatEntities(CurrentUsername))
        {
            List<string> statusList = getPendingStatus(context).Result;
            OrderHeader orderHeader = getOrderHerderByOrderCode(context, model.OrderCode, model.SalesChannelId).Result;

            if (statusList.Contains(orderHeader.Status))
            {
                if (orderHeader != null)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    orderHeader.Remark = model.Remark;
                    context.DBEntry(orderHeader, EntityState.Modified);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

            }

        }
        return new ResponseBaseModel(MessageCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ResponseBaseModel(MessageCode.Fail, ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

**Fail Methods**

```
public async Task<ResponseBaseModel> AddOrderRemark2(AddOrderRemarkRequestModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (ChatEntities context = new ChatEntities(CurrentUsername))
        {
            List<string> statusList = getPendingStatus(context).Result;
            OrderHeader orderHeader = getOrderHerderByOrderCode(context, model.OrderCode, model.SalesChannelId).Result;

            if (statusList.Contains(orderHeader.Status))
            {
                if (orderHeader != null)
                {
                    orderHeader.Remark = model.Remark;
                    context.DBEntry(orderHeader, EntityState.Modified);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                }

            }

        }
        return new ResponseBaseModel(MessageCode.OK);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return new ResponseBaseModel(MessageCode.Fail, ex.InnerException.Message);
    }
}
```

**Edit**

I have realise that there are two APIs call at the same times from client sides. Moreover, these two APIs update on the same table `'OrderHeader'` which contain both **receiver info** and **remark** that why it causes this issue!!. How can I prevent this issue guys?

```
        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("AddReceiverAddress")]
        [ChatAuthentication]
        public async Task<ResponseBaseModel> AddReceiverAddress(AddReceiverAddressRequestModel model)
        {
            return _orderService.Value.AddReceiverAddress(model).Result;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [ActionName("AddOrderRemark")]
        [ChatAuthentication]
        public async Task<ResponseBaseModel> AddOrderRemark(AddOrderRemarkRequestModel model)
        {
            return _orderService.Value.AddOrderRemark(model).Result;
        }
```

Comment: Don't use `getOrderHerderByOrderCode().Result`, but await it properly: `await getOrderHerderByOrderCode()`

Comment: It is considered good practice to end an async method with Async: `getPendingStatusAsync()` and `AddOrderRemark2Async()` for clarity. You could also use ` await SaveChangesAsync()` instead of `SaveChanges()`

Comment: @PeterBruins Thank you for comment I have edit question. can you help me solved

Comment: Your update in question is really confusing (maybe only for me). But if both methods update same table and both of them get called at the same time then why don't you merge them into a single method?

Comment: Your question lack a lot of info. Does the method *always* fail? Did you implement optimistic concurrency? Do you get exceptions? What happens in this extension method `DBEntry`?

Answer (score 3):

You are not using async properly.  Try this instead

```
public async Task<ResponseBaseModel> AddOrderRemark2(AddOrderRemarkRequestModel model)
{
    try
    {
        using (ChatEntities context = new ChatEntities(CurrentUsername))
        {
            List<string> statusList = await getPendingStatus(context);
            OrderHeader orderHeader = await getOrderHerderByOrderCode(context, model.OrderCode, model.SalesChannelId);
```

Comment: thank you I have edit  question, that may be root cause. can you help me solved.

Comment: This doesn't explain why OP code is not working. While calling async method synchronously is not considered a good practice, it is valid to do so. The behavior of the called method should not be different.

Answer (score 0):

When you call this method, did you `await` or `Wait()` for a result?

When you call the method you have to do either one of them as below sample.

```
await AddOrderRemark2(model);
```

Or

```
AddOrderRemark2(model).Wait();
```

Comment: using `.Wait()` is almost always a bad idea https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html

Comment: thank you I have edit  question, that may be root cause. can you help me solved.

Comment: And the answer is when he enter multi-line input